# polymer 2.0. How to open dialog in parent element from child?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I am using Polymer Starter Kit 2.I created a paper-dialog and event in my-app.html:

```
<paper-dialog id="animated" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" with-backdrop>
              <h2>Dialog Title</h2>              
    </paper-dialog>
---------------------------------------------------------------
feedback(){
            this.$.animated.open();
        }
```

And now I want to open a this dialog from child View1 from iron-pages. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could either raise an event in the child element and open the dialog when you receive it or pass a callback function to the child that gets called whenever you want to open the dialog.

Events documentation:
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events

Comment: Could you give an example, please?

Comment: @user2497209 I added a link to the documentation of polymer, it contains basic examples and explains the event system more thoroughly

Comment: I still do not understand. I want to create a button in a child element and hang an event "feedback" on it. Or am I not right in reasoning? Should I turn to the paper-dialog by id from child element?

Comment: @user2497209 the idea is to raise (fire) the event when the button in the child element is clicked.

In the parent, handle the event and call the open method of the dialog

Comment: Still dont understand. Thanks for help. If you find an example, I will be very grateful to you

Comment: A sample is provided on the page given by Josef. See the section of Fire custom events, https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events#custom-events